# How to match fields from two lists and further filter based upon the values in subsequent fields?

Tags: python, list, loops, filter, iterator

EDIT: My question was answered on reddit. Here is the link if anyone is interested in the answer to this problem https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/42ibhg/how_to_match_fields_from_two_lists_and_further/

I am attempting to get the pos and alt strings from file1 to match up with what is in 
file2, fairly simple. However, file2 has values in the 17th split element/column to the 
last element/column (340th) which contains string such as 1/1:1.2.2:51:12 which
I also want to filter for.

I want to extract the rows from file2 that contain/match the pos and alt from file1. 
Thereafter, I want to further filter the matched results that only contain certain 
values in the 17th split element/column onwards. But to do so the values would have to 
be split by ":" so I can filter for split[0] = "1/1" and split[2] > 50. The problem is 
I have no idea how to do this.

I imagine I will have to iterate over these and split but I am not sure how to do this 
as the code is presently in a loop and the values I want to filter are in columns not rows.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, I have sat with this problem since Friday and 
have yet to find a solution.

```
import os,itertools,re
file1 = open("file1.txt","r")
file2 = open("file2.txt","r")

matched = []

for (x),(y) in itertools.product(file2,file1):
    if not x.startswith("#"):
            cells_y = y.split("\t")
            pos_y = cells[0]
            alt_y = cells[3]

            cells_x = x.split("\t")
            pos_x = cells_x[0]+":"+cells_x[1]
            alt_x = cells_x[4]

            if pos_y in pos_x and alt_y in alt_x:
                    matched.append(x)

for z in matched:
    cells_z = z.split("\t")
    if cells_z[16:len(cells_z)]:
```

Comment: Where are `i` and `cells` initialized?

Comment: This was an error in my code, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear, but you might mean this:

```
for (x),(y) in itertools.product(file2,file1):
    if x.startswith("#"):
        continue

    cells_y = y.split("\t")
    pos_y = cells[0]
    alt_y = cells[3]

    cells_x = x.split("\t")
    pos_x = cells_x[0]+":"+cells_x[1]
    alt_x = cells_x[4]

    if pos_y != pos_x: continue
    if alt_y != alt_x: continue

    extra_match = False

    for f in range(17, 341):
        y_extra = y[f].split(':')

        if y_extra[0] != '1/1': continue
        if y_extra[2] <= 50: continue
        extra_match = True
        break

    if not extra_match: continue

    xy = x + y
    matched.append(xy)
```

I chose to concatenate x and y into the matched array, since I wasn't sure whether or not you would want all the data. If not, feel free to go back to just appending x or y.

Comment: Yes this works if I wish to match those conditions (y_extra[0] != '1/1', etc) with the values in y[17] only. However, I need to match the same information with the values in y[18],y[19],y[20].....y[340]. This is what I am having difficulty. Apologies for the lack of clarity, I find this problem quite difficult to express, and thanks for trying to help out.

Comment: I have emended the code, adding support for iterating over the extra fields. See if this improves things any?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the csv library, which can use tab as a delimiter. You can also use a generator and/or guards to make the code a bit more pythonic and efficient. I think your approach with indexes works pretty well, but it would be easy to break when trying to modify down the road, or to update if your file lines change shape. You may wish to create objects (I use NamedTuples in the last part) to represent your lines and make it much easier to read/refine down the road.

Lastly, remember that Python has a shortcut feature with the comparative 'if'

for example:

```
if x_evaluation and y_evaluation:
    do some stuff
```

when x_evaluation returns False, Python will skip y_evaluation entirely. In your code, `cells_x[0]+":"+cells_x[1]` is evaluated every single time you iterate the loop. Instead of storing this value, I wait until the easier alt comparison evaluates to True before doing this (comparatively) heavier/uglier check.

```
import csv

def filter_matching_alt_and_pos(first_file, second_file):
    for x in csv.reader(open(first_file, 'rb'), delimiter='\t'):
        for y in csv.reader(open(second_file, 'rb'), delimiter='\t'):
            # continue will skip the rest of this loop and go to the next value for y
            # this way, we can abort as soon as one value isn't what we want
            # .. todo:: we could make a filter function and even use the filter() built-in depending on needs!
            if x[3] == y[4] and x[0] == ":".join(y[:1]):
                yield x

def match_datestamp_and_alt_and_pos(first_file, second_file):
    for z in filter_matching_alt_and_pos(first_file, second_file):
        for element in z[16:]:
            # I am not sure I fully understood your filter needs for the 2nd half. Here, I split all elements from the 17th onward and look for the two cases you mentioned. This seems like it might be very heavy, but at least we're using generators!
            # same idea as before, we abort as early as possible to avoid needless indexing and checks
            for chunk in element.split(":"):
                # WARNING: if you aren't 100% sure the 2nd element is an int, this is very dangerous
                # here, I use the continue keyword and the negative-check to help eliminate excess overhead. The execution is very similar as above, but might be easier to read/understand and can help speed things along in some cases
                # once again, I do the lighter check before the heavier one
                if not int(chunk[2])> 50:
                    # continue automatically skips to the next iteration on element
                    continue
                if not chunk[:1] == "1/1":
                    continue
                yield z


if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_file = "first.txt"
    second_file = "second.txt"
    # match_datestamp_and_alt_and_pos returns a generator; for loop through it for the lines which matched all 4 cases
    match_datestamp_and_alt_and_pos(first_file=first_file, second_file=second_file)
```

namedtuples for the first part

```
from collections import namedtuple
FirstFileElement = namedtuple("FirstFrameElement", "pos unused1 unused2 alt")
SecondFileElement = namedtuple("SecondFrameElement", "pos1 pos2 unused2 unused3 alt")

def filter_matching_alt_and_pos(first_file, second_file):
    for x in csv.reader(open(first_file, 'rb'), delimiter='\t'):
        for y in csv.reader(open(second_file, 'rb'), delimiter='\t'):
            # continue will skip the rest of this loop and go to the next value for y
            # this way, we can abort as soon as one value isn't what we want
            # .. todo:: we could make a filter function and even use the filter() built-in depending on needs!
            x_element = FirstFileElement(*x)
            y_element = SecondFileElement(*y)
            if x.alt == y.alt and x.pos == ":".join([y.pos1, y.pos2]):
                yield x
```